# Is it possible to merge the four different MySQL Queries along with an if condition in between to avoid java codes?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, join

here is my MySQL table:-

```
pk_id   priority  active  total
--------------------------------
 1       west       0       3
 2       north      0       0
 3       south      1       1
 4       east       0       0
```

Below are my java codes with MySQL quires:-

```
String past_p;
String past_tot;
String new_p;
String new_tot;


//query 1: active= 1 means, past processed data. 

String past_priority = "select priority, total from tbl_priority where active = 1";

        Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet Op=stmt.executeQuery(past_priority);
        if(Op.next()){          
            past_p   =Op.getString("priority");
            past_tot =Op.getString("total ");
            }
//query 2:

 String new_priority = "Select priority, max(total) from tbl_priority";

        ResultSet Np =stmt.executeQuery(new_priority );
        if(Np.next()){ 

            new_p   =Np.getString("priority");
            new_tot =Np.getString("total ");
            }

        if (past_tot >= new_tot){

           return 0;
        }

        else{

   //query 3:

        String update_a= "update tbl_priority set active=0 where NOT (priority=?");


    PreparedStatement upa = conn.prepareStatement(update_a);
    upa.setString(1, new_p);
    upa.executeUpdate();

    // query 4:

        String update_b= "update tbl_priority set active = 1 where priority =?";

    PreparedStatement upb = conn.prepareStatement(update_b);
    upb.setString(1, new_p);
    upb.executeUpdate();
}
```

I am developing a real-time life saving application where time really matters. 
I need to call this function in small intervals, hence i need to optimize the above codes to save processing power and time for execution.

Brief explanation of above function:

query 1:

I need to identify the total value of respective priority with active flag, active=1,

query 2/3/4:

I need the highest total value, have to compare it with the previous processed data. If it is larger that previous value, have to reset the flag of previous processed data and set active=1 with the current highest total value.

on the above example, the current highest (max(total)) is 'west' and past active is south. The active flag of south and west have to be changed after identifying that currently west holds highest value in total.

If those MySQL quires are merged, it will save processing speed and time for execution, right?

Is it possible to merge those MySQL quires and avoid java codes in between to get same result (maybe by using joint function)? I tried several times and failed.

Any piece of code is highly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi, i just need to optimize the above process. I though using sql queries is the solution and i tried nested quires and sql join but failed! Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Well, why don't you make stored procedure that does that .... then you can just avoid your validation inside of code behind and variables? Execution of that small procedure will take like half of second and you will skip all that checks and ifs you got going on there, and at end of procedure just go with select of current priority?

Comment: @Veljko89 Thanks for the response. Selection of current priority is the end of this function, not the entire program. I don't know much about stored procedures. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, it is supposed to be. When there is a change in it (by other functions of program), we need to set active for the highest total

Comment: But in that case why store 'active' at all? It seems like a redundancy ?!

Comment: @Strawberry Status of active is being used by other functions in the program. I need the past and present status, active=1 is considerd as the past status which will be updated by present status, iff the present status max(total) is >= total of active=1.

Comment: @Strawberry Do you think, stored procedures can do the job as Veljko89 suggested?

Comment: @Strawberry I need to set the west as active. There maybe another condition when the total value of west and south are equal, at that time i have to make sure that previously active one still goes ahead with active=1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127277/discussion-between-jasim-and-strawberry).

Comment: I still don't really get it. The 'active' row will be the one with the highest total. The previously active row with the one with the second highest total. In the event of a tie (for first place), all tied rows will be 'active'. What else do you need to know?

Comment: @Strawberry 
Hi, the current status of the table is unprocessed. have to find the max(total) and set the active=1 accordingly. The total= 3 of pk_id= 1 is the last update in the table from other source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one active item at the time you could just look for the highest value of total and reset the status without any search and comparison.

```
SET @pk_id_tmp = (SELECT `pk_id` FROM `tbl_priority`  ORDER BY `total` DESC, `active` DESC LIMIT 1);

UPDATE `tbl_priority` 
SET `active` = CASE `pk_id` WHEN @pk_id_tmp THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. let me test it properly.

Comment: Wow, that worked. Hats off for you. You have just turned a 20 line program in to just 2. Still one more doubt, can you make both the quries in to just one?

Comment: You can use the entire statement in one call.

Comment: glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I just can't help feeling that you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist. Anyway, here's something to think about...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(priority VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,total INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('west',1),
('north',0),
('south',2),
('east',0);

SELECT *
     , CASE FIND_IN_SET(total,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT total ORDER BY total DESC) x FROM my_table)) 
       WHEN 1 THEN 'active' 
       WHEN 2 THEN 'previous' END status 
  FROM my_table;
+----------+-------+----------+
| priority | total | status   |
+----------+-------+----------+
| west     |     1 | previous |
| north    |     0 | NULL     |
| south    |     2 | active   |
| east     |     0 | NULL     |
+----------+-------+----------+

UPDATE my_table SET total = 4 WHERE priority = 'west';

SELECT *
     , CASE FIND_IN_SET(total,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT total ORDER BY total DESC) x FROM my_table)) 
       WHEN 1 THEN 'active' 
       WHEN 2 THEN 'previous' END status 
  FROM my_table;
+----------+-------+----------+
| priority | total | status   |
+----------+-------+----------+
| west     |     4 | active   |
| north    |     0 | NULL     |
| south    |     2 | previous |
| east     |     0 | NULL     |
+----------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort and kindness. am sorry for not able to make you understand the context of my program.